# Making infinte file by assembly program but halt when it isn't suppose to

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

I make a program in assembly using tasm assembler, I'm trying to make an infinite loop of procedure "buat". This procedure makes infinite files by the name random integer. But when I run this program using DOSbox, it only succeeds make around 6 to 3 files and then the program is halted. By the way, I make the executable file of this program as .COM.

I've tried to check the program in emu8086, but emu8086 only able to show me that variable "Rnd" changes infinitely. I'm suspicious that my program halted when it fails to close the file that recently made, because when I try to delete all files that have been created, there will be one file that can't be deleted because it still opened by DOSbox. Is there any limit of instruction that could be run by the TASM? or by DOSbox?

Here is the part of the code that makes infinite files

```
create:
    call buat

buat proc
    ;call loading       
    jmp lop

lop:
    call random
    cmp ax,0
    jg good
    NEG AX

good:
    MOV BX, 10;#4 base, we divide by it
    MOV SI, 0;#4 first position after the "Tnt/" of RndFile
    opt:
        CMP AX, 10000;#4not 5 digits
        JAE bra
        IMUL bx
        JMP opt

bra:
    W:
        MOV DX, 0
        DIV BX ;#3Divide number (AX) by base (BX)
        ADD DL, 48;#3char
        MOV Rnd[SI], DL
        INC SI
        CMP AX, 0
        JE done
    JMP W   

done:      
    mov dl, "."
    mov rnd[si],dl

    inc si
    mov dl, "e"
    mov rnd[si],dl

    inc si
    mov dl, "x"
    mov rnd[si],dl

    inc si
    mov dl, "e"
    mov rnd[si],dl

    lea dx, rnd
    mov cx, 0h
    mov ah, 3Ch
    int 21h

    mov ah, 3Eh
    int 21h
    jmp lop

    ret
endp

randgen proc
    mov ah, 2ch
    int 21h 
    xor ax,ax
    mov al,dl   
    xor dx,dx
    mov bx,10
    div bx

    ret                       
endp

random proc
    call randgen
    mov [ones], dl


    call randgen
    mov [tens], dl


    call randgen
    mov [hundsa], dl 

    mov ax, 0
    mov bx, 0
    mov bl, 10

    mov al, tens
    mul bl 
    mov tens, al

    mov ax, 0
    mov bx, 0
    mov bl, 100

    mov al, hundsa
    mul bl 
    mov hundsa, al
    mov hundsb, ah  

    mov al, hundsa
    mov ah, hundsb
    mov numb, ax

    mov ax, 0
    mov al, tens
    add numb, ax 

    mov ax, 0
    mov al, ones
    add numb, ax
    mov ax, numb
    ret
endp
```

I expect this program will continuously make files unless I close the DosBox

Comment: I'm not sure if this has to do with your problem: You call DOS function `AH=3Ch` which creates a file. Then you call function `AH=3Eh` to close the handler. However, `AH=3Ch` returns the handle in `AX` and it sets the carry flag if creating the file failed. `AH=3Eh` expects the file handle in `BX` and shall not be called if creating the file failed. So you should check the carry flag and copy `AX` to `BX`.

Comment: thanks for your response @MartinRosenau, I've tried to make my program jump to the code part that I used to close the handler if the carry flag is 0, and copy ax to bx before close the handler but the result is still the same. Anyway, I've checked carry flag by emu8086 but the carry flag never become 1 when the code that making files executed.

Comment: The only progress that happened after I try that, is I could delete all files that have been created even though I still open the DOSbox.

Comment: I just tested your program in a virtual machine running MS-DOS 6.22. It works fine and it does not halt. Looking at your program I found out that you don't write a NUL byte after the ".exe". This will not make any problem if it is guaranteed that the corresponding byte is already NUL. Another problem is that your program will hang if `random` returns `AX=0` (you can do `imul` as often as you want, you will never get a number larger than 10000; maybe there are other numbers that behave similarly if `imul` causes an "overflow").

Comment: Under MS-DOS 6.22 only few random numbers (about 50) repeated again and again, but the program did not halt but it created the files with the 50 names again and again. I have to say that I used TASM v 1.0 to assemble and had to adapt the syntax of some lines. Maybe your TASM version understands the syntax of the lines differently and therefore creates wrong code (e.g. your version might understand `mov ax, numb` as `mov ax, offset numb` instead of `mov ax, word ptr [numb]`; TASM v 1.0 explicitly requires the explicit syntax.)